# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\VarificationEmail' not found laravel_version 6+

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

> I am using

`Mail::to($user->email)->send( new VarificationEmail($user));`

> in directory

**App\Http\Controller**

> and

```
VarificationEmail.php
```

> in directory

```
App\Mail\
```

> when submit page then error

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\VarificationEmail' not found
```

> how solved this problem?

Comment: Can you share a full working example of your code, specifically of these two classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `use App\Mail\VarificationEmail;` to the top of your controller. The error here is because you're in the `App\Http\Controller` namespace, so the code cannot find `VarificationEmail`. See the below example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\VarificationEmail;

class Controller
{
...
```

Comment: It is 'App\Http\Controller' file directory not class ...@Giles Correia Morton

Comment: What file are you calling `Mail::to($user->email)->send( new VarificationEmail($user));`? It is in this file you'll need to add the `use App\Mail\VarificationEmail;` line. It doesn't matter where your code is but, in order to utilise the `VarificationEmail` class, you'll need to reference it at the top of the file in this way.

Comment: Thanks @Giles Correia Morton but again this error show...Argument 1 passed to App\Mail\VarificationEmail::__construct() must be an instance of App\Mail\User, instance of App\models\User given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\working_file\laravel_llc05\app\Http\Controllers\backendController.php on line 103

Comment: Hmm, okay. The new error looks like an issue with how you are calling the `User` in `VarificationEmail.php`. It's the same issue in a different place, i.e. the `User` model is not in`App\Mail` namespace, so in your `VarificationEmail` add a `use` statement for the `User` class: `use App\User;`. Please note, I don't know where your `User.php` file is, so you'll need to define the correct path to it in `VarificationEmail.php`, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

you must use this one

```
use App\Mail\VarificationEmail;
```

not this one

```
use App\Http\Controllers\VarificationEmail
```

Comment: It is 'App\Http\Controller' file directory not class ...@Qonvex620

Comment: yes, in your controller copy this use App\Mail\VarificationEmail; on above in order for the laravel to locate your VerificationEmail